# Error when with set Value() function with template form in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to set new value for a template-form after clicking on the item the fields of the form should be filled by the values of clicked item like the photo, when clicked on tomato the form should be filed by tomato details, but I am facing this error during run time :cannot read properties of undefined (reading:'name')

```js
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { ingredient } from 'src/app/shared/ingredient.model';
import { ShoppingListService } from '../shopping-list.rservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shoping-edit',
  templateUrl: './shoping-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shoping-edit.component.css']
})
export class ShopingEditComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('fo', { static: false }) slForm:NgForm

subscription:Subscription 
editMode=false
editedItemindex:number
editedItem:ingredient

  constructor(private sl:ShoppingListService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription=  this.sl.startetEditting.subscribe(
      (index:number)=>{
        this.editedItemindex=index;
        this.editMode=true;
        this.editedItem=this.sl.getIngredient(index)
        this.slForm.setValue(
          {
            name:this.editedItem.name,
            amount:this.editedItem.amount
          }
        )

      }
    )
  }
  onAddItem(form:NgForm)
  {
    const value=form.value;
    
  const newing=new ingredient(value.name,value.amount)
  this.sl.addIngredient(newing)
 

  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if(this.slForm){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()}
}

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="clo-xs-12">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onAddItem(fo)" #fo="ngForm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5 form-group" >
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text"
           id="name"
            class="form-control"
            name="name"
            ngModel
            required
            >
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
          <label for="amount">Amount</label>
          <input type="number"
           id="amount"
           class="form-control"
           name="amount"
           ngModel
           required
           [pattern]="'^[1-9]+[0-9]*$'"
           >
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"[disabled] ="!fo.valid">Add</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Delete</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to replace the dot notation with bracket notation, use `this.editedItem['name']` instead of `this.editedItem.name`

Comment: its deprecated in that way this.editedItem['name']

Comment: kindly be informed that when I start to assign the value to the control of the form it is deprecated and this is the error core.js:6486 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at SafeSubscriber._next (shoping-edit.component.ts:31:34)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:1)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:1)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at Subject.next (Subject.js:39:1)
    at ShoppingListComponent.onEditItem (shopping-list.component.ts:28:29)